# How to get ByteArray from JLabel icon?

Tags: java, database, arrays, jlabel, imageicon

I'm trying to get `ByteArray` from icon of `JLabel` and then store it to my database.
The reason being because when I open image in my `JLabel` it gets resized to 300x300 pixels, so I want to save that resized picture to my database, to keep my database lightweight.
I want to do that 'on the fly' without having to save that resized picture on the disk.

I have no problem to convert the files from the disk to a `ByteArray` and storing those `ByteArrays` in a SQLite database.
But getting the `ByteArray` from an icon of a `JLabel` is a mission impossible for me.
I don't know is it even possible.

So help me out, guys.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The JLabel is simply a placeholder for the image, you are still using the image object. Wouldn't it be easier to simply convert the image into a byte array?

```
File f = new File("img.jpg");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fnew);
ByteArrayOutputStream b =new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", b );
byte[] imageInByte = b.toByteArray();
```

Or if you wanted to retrieve the image from a JLabel you can use:

```
Icon icon = label.getIcon();
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(),
            icon.getIconHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Comment: I know that, but I'm trying somehow to take that icon from JLabel, turn it to Image and then get bytes from that Image. I know there is an easy way, to read it from file. Tnx for the trouble anyway. :D

Comment: The above code does just that. You can take the icon from a JLabel and convert it to a BufferedImage.

Comment: In the future you can refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html